# Adding a date filter in cosmos db not performant

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cosmos db with 4164634 items currently in it. Each one is along the lines of:

```
  {
        "id": "b1bd4070-7df3-4e04-a6b2-4284f3e104f6",
        "jobId": "123",
        "clientID": 1,
        "eventDetails": {
            "Date": "2020-01-16T16:31:45",
            "Type": "Click",
            "PageUrl": "some url",
            "IPAddress": "100.100.100.0",
            "Source": "Foo"
        }
    }
```

If I do a query without a date filter. e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.jobId FROM c 
WHERE c.eventDetails.Source = 'Foo'
```

The RU charge is quite reasonable at around 17 RUs. The response time is also quite quick an has an index lookup time of 0.28 ms.

However if I add a date filter in. e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.jobId FROM c 
WHERE c.eventDetails.Source = 'Foo' 
AND (c.eventDetails.Date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' and '2020-02-29')
```

Then the RU charge goes up to 12397 RUs. It's also slower with an index lookup time of 19516.1499 ms. Despite the fact the second is going to result in a much much smaller result set.

The indexes are the default to index everything and no additional composite indexes have been configured.

Can someone explain why it takes so much more processing and what I can do to optimize?

Comment: How old is this collection? If this is older than a year it may be using our old indexing version which used hash index on strings (your dates here). The newer index version uses range indexes on both strings and numbers and performs much better. In either case, if you could share your index policy from this container it would tell me which index version this container is using. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,Tim. Any reply for @Mark's comment?

Comment: The db is only 3 months old

Comment: Hi @TimGriffiths. I've discussed this with my engineering team. Unfortunately we're not able to suggest what may be going on here. The only thing we could suggest is to open a support ticket so an engineer can look at your container telemetry. Apologies I cannot suggest anything here. Thanks!